# É possível criar uma variável de campos no SQL Firebird?

Tags: sql, select, firebird, dbeaver

Queria saber se é possível criar uma variável de campos no SQL, algo como:

> ***SELECT # FROM table_name***

Sendo # **campos específicos** da minha tabela, **diferente** do * que retornaria todos os campos.

Se tivesse uma maneira de retornar só as chaves primárias compostas já ajudaria, algo como:

> ***SELECT PK FROM table_name***

Utilizo o DBeaver.

Comment: Algo como: `SELECT id_carro FROM carro` ?

Comment: @LeandroPaixão assim eu estaria passando o campo na mão, a ideia seria fazer algo tipo: # = id_carro, id_placa, id_motorista, id_chassi e depois fazer um select # from ...

Comment: Tentou usar as tabelas de metadados ? https://ib-aid.com/download/docs/firebird-language-reference-2.5/fblangref25-appx04-systables.html